# How to fix Error Permission denied after clone or pull git repository to server

Tags: git, bitbucket

I try to clone my projetct from bitbucket to my host server using ssh , when hi is done , i cant update files or delete or do any action , even i try do clear cahe  i always get `Permission denied` error

Answer (score 2):

You probably cloned using a different user than what your server is using to serve the files.

Go into the directory of the repository and make sure the folder `.git` has the correct owner/permissions.

E.g. you can fix the owner with `chown -R www-data .git` if the host servers' git user is `www-data`. If not replace the name with the appropriate user's name.